# PHP - Delete part of a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to  PHP and I have a problem.

I need delete all chars since a symbol (Sorry for my bad english , i'm from argentina)

I have this text :

```
 3,94&#8364;
```

And I need the text is as follows:

```
3,94
```

I tried this by multiple ways but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: @MarcB then for example http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php too. But i think better http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: what are the variations? how does the number change? is it always `&#8364;` after ?

Comment: @Dagon *since a symbol*

Comment: @splash58 i was not clear what the *symbol* was the & or the whole `&#8364;` or ?

Comment: @Dagon Maybe, you are right

Comment: im right in not being sure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this:

Using [strpos](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$string = '3,94&#8364;';
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '&'));
```

or using [strstr](http://php.net/strstr):

```
// Requires PHP 5.3+ due to the true (before_needle) parameter
$string = '3,94&#8364;';
echo strstr($string, '&', true);
```

or using [explode](http://php.net/explode):

```
// Useful if you need to keep the &#8364 part for later
$string = '3,94&#8364;';
list($part_a, $part_b) = explode('&', $string);
echo $part_a;
```

or using [reset](http://php.net/reset):

```
$string = '3,94&#8364;';
echo reset(explode('&', $string));
```

The best suited in your case would be to use `strpos` to find the first occurrence of `&` in the string, and then use `substr` to return the string from the begining until the value returned by `strpos`.

Comment: there are alt least 6 more options you could add ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex: https://regex101.com/r/uY0kH3/1

It will work in [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I will try to remember it @pinkalvansia :)

Answer (score 0):

Another posibility is clean the number and then round it:

```
<?php
    //Option 1: with regular expresions:    
    $val = '3,94&#8364';
    $res = preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]/','',$val);
    var_dump($res); 

    //Option 2: with filter functions:
    $res2 = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
    var_dump($res2);

    //Output: 3,948364


    //If you want to round it:

    $res = substr($res, 0, 4);

    var_dump($res);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
<?php


$string = 3,94&#8364;
$final = str_replace('&#8364' ,'', $string);
echo $final;
```